# flood fill performance issue on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, flood-fill

I am using 4-Way floodfill algorithm.

I have a transparent image with black out line.

That is staring point image(without color).

[image]

And after filling the color in this image it look like this

[image]

Please help me and let me know what can i do for proper fill.

Comment: Can you paste your algorithm?

Comment: please check this here http://pastie.org/8413819

Comment: I am following this example https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill

Comment: You get the solution i am also suffering from same.

Answer (score 0):

I used and implemented myself FloodFill in other projects and the algorithm goes trough the whole draw, looking for closed spaces and then draw inside (or outside) them.

Your problem happens with every tool in the world that fills a draw, and the problem is the same, the spaces are not 100% closed.

The floodfill algorithm goes pixel by pixel and when it detect a black pixel, it stops. For example, the arm of the scuba driver is not thick enough or it has holes on it, and the flood fill algorithm manages to go trough it and not detect it as an empty space.

Nobody here can tell you why unless we take your project and analyse it, so the best I can offer is a guideline about where your error could be.

Comment: but when i am using white background ,it working fine .but as per my requirement i need to use transparent image for that.so after 5 to 6 tap/fill this image look like same.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code with an image that has a very precise defined border around it ([from here](http://looneytunes.wikia.com/wiki/Wile_E._Coyote_and_The_Road_Runner/Gallery?file=Wileecoyte.gif)) and it seems to work OK with that image. I suggest perhaps that if you zoom into your image that there is some grey aliasing around the edges which won't get filled. Perhaps the algorithm has a threshold function that can be tweaked?

Try setting the andTolerance value (I tried 4 which seemed to improve my example).

```
//Call function to flood fill and get new image with filled color
    UIImage *image1 = [self.image floodFillFromPoint:tpoint withColor:newcolor andTolerance:4];
```

Comment: what is mean by threshold function?

Comment: see my edited answer above (threshold is the andTolerance part)